# Golang executable refresh

Tags: go

I have a function which writes/updates a json. But I need to stop the executable, run go build again and re-run the executable to get the json updated in url.

For example, I have a Handler.go file which takes argument from URL as key and runs an if condition and updates the json. So If json value before building the executable is {"Name":"Sneha"} and i pass parameter "Nair" in the url, the json gets updated in the server as {"Name":"Nair"}, but doesnt get updated in the URL. So I have to stop the executable, run go build again and run the executable again to reflect the new json value {"Name":"Nair"} in the URL.

**1. Can somebody please suggest an alternative idea ?**

**2. Can we run go build or go update inside a function?**

Help much appreciated.

PS: I have got URL for goagain.go. But am not sure if that matches my requirement.

Handler.go

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["key"]
    if !ok || len(keys) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'key' is missing")
        return
    }
    key := keys[0]
    log.Println("Url Param 'key' is: " + string(key))
    if key == "java" {

         commands := []string{
        "Version=`java -version`",
        "sed -i -e 's/^\\( *Name: *\\) .*$/        Name:\"Java\",/' Handler.go",
        "sed -i -e 's/^\\( *Version: *\\) .*$/        Version:\" '$Version'\",/' Handler.go",   

    }
        exe_cmd(commands)

    }

    if key == "go" {

         commands := []string{
        "Version=`go version`",
        "sed -i -e 's/^\\( *Name: *\\) .*$/        Name:\"Go\",/' Handler.go",
        "sed -i -e 's/^\\( *Version: *\\) .*$/        Version:\" '$Version'\",/' Handler.go",   

    }
        exe_cmd(commands)

    }

    GetHands := GetHand{

            Name:"java",
            Version:" 1.7.0_71",

            }

if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(GetHands); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

So on running this package, the url shows json value : {"name":"java","version":" 1.7.0_71"}
If I call url : http://localhost:8080/?key=go this Handler.go gets updated to,

```
GetHands := GetHand{

        Name:"go",
        Version:" 1.9",

        }
```

If I stop the executable, 
run go build again and run executable again the url gets returned as :{"name":"go","version":" 1.9"}

So basically I need dynamic url which on hitting the http:/localhost/?key=go would return go's corresponding value annd htpp://localhost/?key=java would return java's corresponding value. This should be attained without restarting the executable or re-running the go build

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you're asking is not clear at all. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you asking if you can avoid re-compiling your Go application after making changes to its source code? The answer is obviously "no".

Comment: I have difficutly understanding "but doesnt gets updated in the URL". What do you mean by that? And, do you change your source code between (re)building? If you do, please show what you change so we can see if it is possible to make it a variable instead of constants.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart : so is there any way to re-compile go application from within any go code. For example after updating the json, can I run a go build/ go update from the same function? Apologies If my question looks absurd, but I need to build a dynamic web url, where if I pass an argument in URL, should update the json and in return update the URL content as well

Comment: We still don't know what you mean. Do you want to have a json config file that tells you what URL to serve and need to change the http handler based on the config settings? If so, you can just have a handler for `/` and do the URI check yourself. Again, please include code.

Comment: While it is possible to run `go run` or `go build` from a go executable, it is not likely to be a good idea. I too ask you to give more information.

Comment: JSON isn't Go code, it's not compiled at all, so this question is unclear - please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: @Marc : I hope I am clear now

Comment: @leafbebop : Please check my edit and let me know. Or else please let me know how to run go build from a go executable

Comment: If you just want the current go or java version, you can just capture the output of the commands you ran and update the returned value that way.

Comment: @Marc : No I have set of other commands as well. around 5 or 6 commands for 1 application and I need them in json format only

Comment: Ok, so you need the output of some executables. Run them, parse their stdout, save the results in a struct, and marshal that as json. I don't see what recompiling has to do with anything. And if you need to persist something across restarts of your binary, save the state to a file.

Comment: Your code amazed me. You just change your source code based on request, that is not something happens everyday. But to be honest, it is not a good practice. I will write an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite difficult to understand exactly what you want. But I suspect that is essence you simply want to extract the output from a shell command and write it to JSON.

For this there is no need to modify the Handler.go file or do `go build`. You can simply write the output directly into the `GetHand` structure.

A basic example is as follows :

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
    )

    var cmds = map[string][]string{
        "go":   []string{"/usr/local/go/bin/go", "version"},
        "java": []string{"java", "-version"},
    }

    type GetHand struct {
        Name    string
        Version string
    }

    func handleKey(key string) (*GetHand, error) {

        cmd := cmds[key]
        if cmd == nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("No such key : %v", key)
        }

        b, err := exec.Command("/usr/local/go/bin/go", "version").Output()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return &GetHand{
            Name:    key,
            Version: string(b),
        }, nil
    }

    func main() {
        h, err := handleKey("go")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(h)

        h, err = handleKey("java")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(h)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your problem? It is still unclear how the URI issue relates to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code with all those `sed` tried to modify yor source code. It does not work that way. Some ancient practices (usually using bash) auctually did that kind of staff but it is outdated and problemtic.

As for go, you sure know go is a **compiled language**, which compiles *source code* into *binaries*. In that way, any modification to the source code will not affect binaries, and resulting the process running unaware of that. In that sense, modifying the source code by the process it self is wrong and uneffective. Even if it is possible to use compiler to rebuild binaries, it is going to be both dangerous and inefficient. Do not do it that way.

In your specified case, there is a much better and a much common practice: **variable**. You sure use it everyday. It would be the simplest to just set the fields of `GetHands` to needed value. By doing that, your response to each request (what you call URL, but it is wrong) will change because the fields of GetHands change as *variable*.

I write the code below:

```
import (
    "os/exec"
    "regex"
    "runtime"
)

var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`version \"(.+)\"`)

func GetJavaVersion() string {
    cmd := exec.Command("Java", "-version")
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(pattern.FindSubmatch(out)[1])
}

func GetGoVersion() string {
    return runtime.Version()[2:]
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["key"]
    if !ok || len(keys) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'key' is missing")
        return
    }
    key := keys[0]
    log.Println("Url Param 'key' is: " + string(key))

    var GetHands GetHand

    if key == "java" {
        GetHands = GetHand{Name: "java", Version: GetJavaVersion()}
    }

    if key == "go" {
        GetHands = GetHand{Name: "go", Version: GetGoVersion()}
    }

    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(GetHands); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

So, for go, you can auctually get the version info from package `runtime`, though the info started with "go". You can simply slice it. And for java, you would have to run a command: The same as your orignal code: `java -version`. But instead of passing it to `sed`, you get the output from it by using `Command.Output` and then use a `regexp` to find the version information. `regexp` is a very useful tool to get info from strings. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: Thanks a lot @leaf bebop. Thats exactly what I need. But I have a lot number of applications in my server and for each application I cannot write return function as you have mentioned for Version. Is there any work around for that?

Comment: Also getting the follwoing error for java version,
http: panic serving 10.226.199.222:64464: runtime error: index out of range

Comment: Why you can not write such function? What difficulty did you meet? Please provide more information. @snehasurendranathan.

Comment: It appears to be not matching my regexp. You need to alter it according to the auctual output of "Java version".

Comment: In case I need to check the version by grepping, ls-lart /somepath | grep socket| cut -d '-' -f2, how to return it to function ? 
@leaf bebop

Comment: I see you are really good at Unix tools. Go can access libraries see "ReadDir" in "io/ioutil", and after that you need to learn regexp and string manipulation in golang. There are many guides easily accessible by googling. I am on mobile so I won't code it for you. But if you still have problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks alot @leaf bebop, One last help I need,

If I click on http:localhost:8080/Go It should dynamically return its version, name, etc and if I replace it with http://localhost:8080/<someotherapplication> It should dynamically return its details like version, name etc. Earlier we had set it for java and go. So  Is that posiible to do it dynamically and if a particular application is not present, it should output result isnt available. Is that possible?

Comment: I am new to Go and this whole concept, So really sorry for absurd questions.

Comment: It is possible. Now you have so much `if`,  you can change it into `switch` and use a `defualt` to handle … well, default cases. I think maybe you should go through the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)